# vs22 cmake include path doesn't work for new vcpkg packages

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, vcpkg

I have a project in VS22 17.9.2 using CMake and VC package on WSL:Ubuntu.
redis++ and nlogmann-json packages are included and they work fine.

When I added a new package ASIO, VS intellisense doesn't seem to see it in includes.

#include <asio.hpp> is not recognized as a valid path even though I can see it in my vcpkg_installed/x64-window/include.

Is there some magic to determine what it allows to be used?
I have it included in CMakeLists.txt and it builds fine.

[image]

Comment: I still don't understand how the include directories work, but I did find a workaround which seems to work on linux.

To my CMakeLists.txt I added
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES} "../vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include")